# Download an asset in Unity build at runtime without Asset Bundle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

One way to download an asset from the server is to make an asset bundle, upload it at a specific URL, download that bundle in the unity project at runtime. Lastly, unload the asset to use it is the unity.

But my scenario to allow the user to upload an asset of a choice to the server and download it in the unity project as an asset.

Is there any other way to perform this task?

Comment: I stumbled across a similar problem about a year ago. Back then the answer was simple: no! We had to start writing our own serialization API. The only way to add assets to the game in run time was through Asset bundles or Having -generic- assets that can read meta-files and create your content from them. Might do the trick for some script attributes or images, but with models and actual scripts this starts to get tricky. I don't think Unity added much more modding support since then.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do directly how you can with Asset bundle or Resource Folder.

The only way to feet your need is making it manually by script on runtime. Parsing the info of the downloaded file, and building your mesh, textures, materials, and all what you need.